# GWT Pull Parser Implementation?

Tags: gwt, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am working on a GWT project which has to run on phones,

The project is required to parse large xml files and since phones are tight on memory i am refraining from using the XML DOm parger bundled with GWT.

In my view the Pull Parser will be apt here. Is there a GWT implementation of the Pull Parser?? It will help reduce the memory required for parsing large XML files...

Thanks,
Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse large files of xml on phones, you will likely hit memory limits of different phones pretty early.

Maybe there is an alternative approach (parse the files server side) and give the relavant information to the phones in a faster format like json.

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree... JSON seems like a good solution!!! did some digging and the following link also shows how to parse and convert json objects to java for GWT coding

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/JSON.html